# ExtJs 4.1 TypeError: 'listener.fireFn is undefined' on grid selectionchange event in controller

Tags: extjs, undefined, extjs4.1

It's very similar question to already posted issue http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?245591

Here is my code for Grid (please note that commented listener declared in grid works fine)

```
Ext.define( 'Fast.view.sales.SalesForecastDealersGrid ' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.SalesForecastDealersGrid' ,
    selModel: Ext.create( 'Ext.selection.CheckboxModel' ),// sm,
    requires:[ 'Ext.toolbar.Paging'],
    columnLines: true,
    store: 'sales.SalesForecastDealers', //'sales.ProductByAccount',

    columns: [{text: 'Dealer Id',hidden: true ,flex:1,dataIndex:'dealerId' },
              {text: 'Customer Name',flex:1,sortable: true,dataIndex: 'dealerName' },
              {text: 'Sales Ids',hidden: true,flex:1,sortable: false ,dataIndex:'salesIds' }],

       initComponent: function () {

        this .dockedItems = [
        {
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar' , dock:'bottom' ,
            store: 'sales.SalesMonthFct' ,//localStore,
            displayInfo: true ,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying ProductByAccount {0} - {1} of {2}' +'&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp',
            emptyMsg: "No ProductByAccount to display"
        }];
        this .callParent(arguments);
       } /*,
listeners:{
        selectionchange : function(model, records) {
       // var records = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
       alert('section changed handler');
    }}*/    

});
```

and for Controller

```
Ext.define( 'Fast.controller.sales.SalesForecastController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    stores: ['sales.SalesWeekFct' ,'sales.SalesMonthFct' ,'sales.SalesForecastDealers' ],
    models: [ 'sales.SalesWeekFctModel', 'sales.SalesMonthFctModel' ],
    views: ['sales.SalesForecastWeeklyGrid' ,'sales.SalesForecastMonthlyGrid' ,'sales. SalesForecastDealersGrid' ],
    refs: [{ref: 'SalesForecastWeeklyGrid',selector: 'SalesForecastWeeklyGrid' }
          ,{ref: 'SalesForecastMonthlyGrid' ,selector: 'SalesForecastMonthlyGrid' }
          ,{ref: 'SalesForecastDealersGrid ',selector: 'SalesForecastDealersGrid '}
          ],

       init: function () {
    this .control({
    //'SalesForecastDealersGrid [action=change]': {selectionchange: this.dealerSelectionChange},
    'SalesForecastDealersGrid ': {selectionchange: this .dealerSelectionChange}
    });
    },

    dealerSelectionChanged : function (model, records) {
    //var records = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
       alert( 'Controllers section changed handler' );
    }
});
```

as you notice I've commented line "'SalesForecastDealersGrid [action=change]': {selectionchange : this.dealerSelectionChange}," because I can't find any documentation about that '[action=change]' and it simply does not fire anything in my case.

with my code when I click on grid row I'm getting an error message in console

```
TypeError: listener.fireFn is undefined
...listener && listener.fireFn.apply(listener.scope || me.observable, args) === fal...
```

Any idea what I can try next?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The space between `this` and `.dealerSelectionChange` is a typo, right? Might just as well cause the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller not have function:

```
selectionchange: this .dealerSelectionChange
```

because your function name is:

```
dealerSelectionChanged : function (model, records)
```